# Express Sessions and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, session

I'm trying to wrap my head around sessions right now.. At the moment, I have a express/NodeJS app that uses query parameters to store values from a script that looks like this

**script** **snippet:**

```
curl localhost:3000/register?name=bob\&width=13.970000\&time=0
curl localhost:3000/wheels?left=0.000000\&right=0.000000\&time=0 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/echo?dist=9.220000\&time=10 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/line?l1=1\&l2=1\&l3=1\&time=20 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/other?ir=0\&time=30 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/wheels?left=3.000000\&right=3.000000\&time=100 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/echo?dist=9.220000\&time=110 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/line?l1=1\&l2=1\&l3=1\&time=120 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/other?ir=0\&time=130 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/wheels?left=3.000000\&right=3.000000\&time=200 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/echo?dist=9.220000\&time=210 --cookie "USER=bob"
curl localhost:3000/line?l1=1\&l2=1\&l3=1\&time=220 --cookie "USER=bob"
```

I have been able to store each piece of data from name, width, left, right, l1, l2, etc into a database on MySQL. I've even created a nice UI to browse the database and filter through it. The next part of my project is to now create a way to browse through the various sessions and see whether they are active or not... But, I'm having issues on trying to do this.

First, some questions:

1. How do I store these sessions to mysql?
2. How does a session link to information that the user stores in a
   database? For instance, when I create the UI to browse particular
   sessions, I want to be able to click on a session and then view the
   name, width, left, right, l1, l2, etc information that they stored
   while that user was logged in?

I've read through the express-sessions documentation and it's really sort of vague on the database information I'm looking for. If this doesn't make sense then I'm VERY sorry. I'm finding out half the battle for me is putting my issues into words, but I'm trying my best to learn express, node js, and mysql by putting my best foot forward on this project. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

with Express-session for mysql you use connector like https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session , and as given basic example you can setup that your express-session will be managed in mysql database.

when you configure this with app.use(--) in your application.  As it will be a middle ware in the node application. you will have access to a **req.session** object

**Simple use case**
   1.After user login you have user data you can add that info to `req.session.user = {...userInfo};`
   2. in other call where you access req object , after setting session you can use to retrieve info .. `const userInfo = req.session.user;`
   and as you want mysql to save session info , so as per setup session
   will be manged with respect to that.

you have access to methods like

```
req.session.destroy(function(err) {
  // cannot access session here -- you can use it at logout time or clear
})
```